# Adding attributes to project - arguments imply differing number of rows?

Tags: r

I created a project from csv files. I saved my attribute details as the variable attributes but when I try to add them using xAddAttributesToProject, i get the message:

```
Error in data.frame(colnames(ATT1), Mode, AttributesDescription) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 1, 6
```

Below is how I created my project, added to it, and how I am adding attributes:

```
Assignment3 <- xCreateProject(
  GeneralDescription = "Data from observing sunglasses company",
  NetworkName = "Frienship Network",
  NETFILE = "DSC_480 Midterm_Friendship Network.csv",
  FileType = "csv",
  InFormatType = "AdjMat",
  NetworkDescription = "If members interact as friends",
  Mode = c("People"),
  Directed = TRUE,  # set directed to true 
  Loops = TRUE,
  Values = "Ordinal",
  Class = "matrix",
  References = "None :)")

# Add Coworker Network
Assignment3 <- xAddToProject(
  ProjectName = Assignment3,
  NetworkName = "Coworker Network",
  NETFILE1 = "DSC_480 Midterm_Coworker Network.csv",
  FileType = "csv",
  InFormatType = "AdjMat",
  NetworkDescription = "If members interact as coworkers",
  Mode = c("People"),
  Directed = TRUE, # set directed to true 
  Loops = TRUE,
  Values = "Ordinal",
  Class = "matrix")

# Add Attributes
Assignment3 <- xAddAttributesToProject(
  ProjectName = Assignment3,
  ATTFILE1 = attributes,
  FileType= "Robject",
  Mode=c("People"),
  AttributesDescription = c("Age",
                            "Gender",
                            "Department",
                            "Years at Company",
                            "Hair Color",
                            "Hobby"))
```